# Convert String to uint8_t for Arduino C++

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

I'm trying to send a user input `String` type over Bluetooth with function

```cpp
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
SerialBT.write()
```

But the function won't accept String, but instead it accepts `uint8_t`.
I tried some conversions like

```cpp
char buf[packet.length()];
memcpy(buf, packet.c_str(), packet.length());
SerialBT.write(buf, packet.length());
```

But it shows an error

`invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]`

Could please someone show me how to convert it right?
Thanks

Comment: `SerialBT.write(static_cast<const uint8_t *>(packet.c_str()), packet.length())` or `uint8_t buf ...`

Comment: @KIIV thanks for comment, your code show this: 'invalid static_cast from type 'const char*' to type 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'}'

Comment: Ok, if it's not enough, there is more forcefull variant:  `SerialBT.write(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(packet.c_str()), packet.length())` or it's C equivalent `SerialBT.write((const uint8_t *) packet.c_str(), packet.length());`

Comment: `uint8_t buf[packet.length()];`?